# Is it possible to make software from autocad? use its sdk in own application development

Tags: graphics, box2d, autodesk, solidworks

I am about to start develop application for machnic tools and drawings. Is there any existing sdk so i can use it with my application? are Audodesk, 3D Max or solidworks provide to build code to develop software from there sdk.

Please help me if anyone knows regarding my query

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all packages you mentioned have SDK:

- [AutoCAD ObjectARX](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=773204)
- [SolidWorks API](http://help.solidworks.com/2013/English/api/sldworksapiprogguide/Welcome.htm)
- [3ds Max SDK Programmer's Guide](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-SDK-Programmer-Guide/)

You may also want to consider OEM programs to expands the standard capabilities under your branding:

- [SolidWorks OEM Program](http://www.solidworks.com/sw/partners/oem_program.htm)
- [AutoCAD OEM](http://www.techsoft3d.com/our-products/autodesk-autocad-oem)